# In what android activity state should one be opening and closing database connections?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, sqlite

I have a commercial application that is almost finished. It has 8 list activities and 4 detail activities and a bunch of other good stuff going on.

When I started out (and was new to Android development), in each method that I needed a database connection, I created a new SQLiteOpenHelper subclass instance and database connection and then closed the connection at the end of the method. This seemed to do bad things.

Complicating everything is that I need to install my data upon first launch. I have a REST app to access and have cached some data from it. I seem to run out of memory when I try to load one of the tables even when I use the JSONReader class in GSON and not just regular InputStreamReader functionality. So, it is supposed to read in objects one at a time. But it still runs out of memory on emulators with <= 1 GB memory.

So, then I started using a singleton, with a synchronized getter, for the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass instance. Doing this, should I still be able to get db connection objects and close them within my methods? This did not seem to work.

Now I am often using a SimpleCursorAdapter subclass for the list activities. This seems to move the problem a bit but not fix it or make it worse.

See this diagram of the activities and when they run:

http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Seeing this, I think I should be able to create the database connection in the onStart call and close it and null the db connection object in the onStop call. No? When I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter subclass, I am loading the adapter in the onStart call and changing the cursor for null in the onStop call. Is this wrong? Apparently it is.

I have a detail activity with the db connection ivar in the class scope. I open the db connection in onStart and close it in onStop. So, why am I getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase" error in my onClick method? The onClick gets called between the onStart and onStop calls, yes? So what the heck gives?

Right now I have a helper method which takes the db connection instance as a parameter and checks it and either returns it, if it is open, or sends back a new, open instance if not.

So, should I need to call this method every 5 or 10 lines in my code? I do not think so, but that is how it feels. I am *only* closing the db connection objects in onStop methods. Why should this be a problem? Should I just not close anything? It will leak, but it may not crash. But that seems wrong. Hmph.

How many db connection objects do I really have? Only one in the entire app? Only one per thread? Some other number? How do I close them so that they are not leaked without causing crashes?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: in my experience singleton is the way to go.

Comment: Singleton for the database connection instance also? For the entire life of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Database is my class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

In my case the singleton will work for the hole application.

Each activity that needs to access the database will create an instace of the appropiated database class ie. Categories.

In the constructor of Categories class i have:

```
public DatabaseCategory(){
    db = DatabaseStorage.get(App.getContext()).getSqlitedatabase();
}
```

So basically the first activity that needs to access the DB will create/open o open the database and will remain opend until the aplication finishes.

Singleton:

```
public class DatabaseStorage {

private static final String TAG = DatabaseStorage.class.getSimpleName();

private static Database database = null;

private DatabaseStorage(){
}

public static Database get(Context context){
    if (database == null){
        database = new Database(context);

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling createDataBase Method");
            database.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling openDataBase Method");
            database.openDataBase(false);
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
    }
    if (database.isOpen() == false){
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling openDataBase Method");
            database.openDataBase(false);
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Returning previous Database");
    }

    return database;
}
}
```

Comment: I use a singleton for the SQLiteOpenHelper subclass instance also. That is not the question. How do you manage the SQLiteDatabase objects, which represent a connection to the database?

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your question. i've updated my answer maybe it's not the best but its what have worked for me.

Comment: Sorry but this is not making sense. Where is the openDataBase(boolean) method coming from? You say this class inherits from SQLLiteOpenHelper, but it does not have this method. The SQLLiteOpenHelper class is supposed to manage databases. How do you manage database connection instances, which are different?

Comment: Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper, It's a helper not a database, SQLiteDatabase has the open method. in SQLiteOpenHelper I implement all the utility methos to handle the database. I.E. createDataBase - will check if the database exist or not if does not exist it will create one and copy the one shipped on the asset forlder to the appropiated android database location. openDataBase will call the appopiate method to open the database in OPEN_READWRITE or OPEN_READONLY mode.

Comment: The first line of your answer says: "Database is my class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper." Line 5 of your code says "private static Database database = null;". Line 31 of your code says "database.openDataBase(false);". So what class implements openDatabase()? If you cannot be clear, please don't answer. It does not help anyone.

Comment: Sorry that you can't understandt me. Your attitude is so RUDE. Whish you luck in our life.

Comment: Yep, my 4 year old son says the same thing. I am SO RUDE. :-)

Comment: He MUST be very proud of you. Im sure